# Sum a double after split in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am pulling data from a txt file that looks like this

Name,123

```
   Dim total As Double = 0

    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("file path")
        'Dim t As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim parts As String() = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim firstPart As String = parts(1)
        total += Double.Parse(firstPart)
```

it is saying that parts(1) is out of range. Any help wold be appreciated

Comment: When the debugger halts the program due to the exception, what is the value of `line`?  Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: right now there is only two lines for testing   bob,10 /n chuck,20         firstpart has a value of 10 in the debuger

Comment: Right... but your code *should* work if the input is in the format you specified above.  Something has to be off with the data you are parsing.  I'm guessing a blank line at the end of the file as @Trevor suggested.  You can use the debugger to help you find out exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly one of the lines either doesn't contain a separator, or it contains no text at all.

You should add a check to ignore such lines:

```
If parts.Length < 2 Then Continue For 'There are not enough parts. Continue with the next line instead.

Dim firstPart As String = parts(1)
total += Double.Parse(firstPart)
```

- [**The `Continue` Statement - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx)

Comment: @liquidacid : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

First part would be parts(0) since arrays are enumerated 0 to N.. but whatever.
You should also test for blank lines if there can be any. The latter is often an issue with text files that end on a new line.

Comment: I am trying to get the numbers so parts(1) would be after the split correct?

Comment: yup... it just confused me

Comment: Personally, when doing such things, I prefer to test to see if the line "looks" like it is in the right format, e.g. test to see if the line contains the required separators.

Comment: Checking the length of the returned array for the expected number of parts is usually faster and more reliable.